# Prove *directly*: Even perfect squares have even square roots.

Tags: number-theory

Is it possible to prove **directly** that even perfect squares have even square roots? Or, symbolically:

$\forall n \in \mathbb{Z},\ \ n^2 \text{ is even } \Rightarrow n \text{ is even }$

The indirect proof by contraposition or contradiction is easy to reach, I'm looking for a direct proof. Trying to prove a point to my students.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $n=m^2$.  Let $m=\prod p_i^{n_i} $ be the unique prime factorization of $m $.  Then $n^2=\prod p_i^{2n_i} $ is the prime factorization of $n^2$.  As $n^2$ is even one of those primes is $2$.  Those are the primes that factor $m $ so $m $ is even.

Comment: I never understood the motivation for this kind of question. Seems like asking "can you prove it without using the letter e." Have you checked to make sure that what you used, mainly the unique factorization theorem, has a direct proof? Because if it didn't then you'd just be sweeping a proof by contradiction under the rug, right?

Comment: Yeah, me too.  Although as a student I had a tendency to over rely on proofs by contradiction and so it could be argued to be good practice to "agressively" look for direct proofs then to "passively" be led by where the contradiction leads.  You have a point that uft could rely on proof by contra.  But that, I suppose depends on *why* the op wants a direct proof.

Comment: To be honest, my motivation has been to show to my students that oftentimes, a proof by contraposition / contradiction is more straightforward than a direct proof. So sure, it requires that you go over the learning curve to understand the logic behind them when you observe them the first time, but they are well worth it in the long run.

Comment: You're saying that your students are initially *reluctant* to prove by contradiction?  It is interesting that that is so for initial students and then the oncce they become math students they tend to (as I did) overdo proof by contradiction to the point of not being able to have instinct for direct proofs.

Comment: THis is perhaps not one of the best examples of a proof by contradiction.  The best of course is that there are infinite primes.  Of course that it of the nature of proving something is *not*, so a proof by contradiction is somewhat more natural...

Answer (score 5):

I don't know if you consider this direct enough, but since $2$ is a prime, and since $p|ab$ implies either $p|a$ or $p|b$, that tells you that $2|n^2$ implies that $2|n$.

Comment: Another good one. Thanks.